# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. at new Rr

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I checked my rules in firebase and the firestore.rules file in my project, but I can't figure what is causing this.

My HTML code.

```html
 <form id="Login" class="input-group">
                    <input id="firstName" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="First Name" required>
                    <input id="lastName" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                    <input id="Major" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Major" required>
                    <input id="Academicyearr" type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Academic Year" required>
                    <button id="write_Test" type="submit" class="submit-buton"> Test Write </button>
                </form>
```

This is the java script code

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();
const updateForm = document.querySelector('#Login');
updateForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        console.log(user.uid);
        if(user) {
            db.collection('Users').doc(user.uid).set({

                // email: updateForm['update-email'].value,
                name: updateForm['firstName'].value,
                // dob: updateForm['update-dob'].value,
                // phone: updateForm['update-phone'].value

            })
        } 
    });
});
```

This is what my rule looks like in my firestore

```html
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

        //match logged in user doc in users collection
    match /Users/{userId} {
      allow read, write, update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

The error is

Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

which appears in the console, when I run my webapp locally.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, go easy on me I'm very new to firebase.

Comment: What is `console.log(user.uid);` showing?

Comment: The uid of the user I am logged in as

Comment: I am not asking what it is meant to show, I am asking what it is actually showing

Comment: Also note that your two rules are overlapping, `create` is included in `write`

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation for user management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) you can find information on how to manage users.

This is how you can update a user according to the [example in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile):

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jane Q. User",
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```